# Customized Tomcat JNDI datasource

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I have multiple webapps which use the same database. Until recently I've been using the JNDI datasource like so:

server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbPool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="100" minIdle="10" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000" 
          username="username" password="password" 
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"/>
```

context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service1DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service2DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service3DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service4DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Server configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(String dataSourceJndiName) {
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    lookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource;
    try {
        dataSource = lookup.getDataSource(dataSourceJndiName);
    } catch (DataSourceLookupFailureException e) {
        log.error("Cannot establish database connection", e)
        throw e;
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

Now I need to start configuring the database dialect (which has been hardcoded so far) in the JNDI resource. My Tomcat and server configurations now look like this:

server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dbPool" auth="Container" type="my.webapp.CustomDataSource"
          maxActive="100" minIdle="10" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000" 
          username="username" password="password" 
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          factory="my.webapp.CustomDataSourceFactory"
          dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"/>
```

context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service1DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="my.webapp.CustomDataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service2DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="my.webapp.CustomDataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service3DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="my.webapp.CustomDataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/service4DB" global="jdbc/dbPool" type="my.webapp.CustomDataSource"/>
```

CustomDataSourceFactory implementation (important stuff copied over from org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory with the dialect squeezed in):

```
public class CustomDataSourceFactory extends DataSourceFactory {

    private static final String PROP_DIALECT = "dialect";
    private static final String[] CUSTOM_PROPERTIES = new String[]{PROP_DIALECT};
    private static final String[] PROPERTIES = ArrayUtils.addAll(ALL_PROPERTIES, CUSTOM_PROPERTIES);

    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws Exception {
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            for (int i = 0; i < PROPERTIES.length; ++i) {
                String propertyName = PROPERTIES[i];
                RefAddr ra = ref.get(propertyName);
                if (ra != null) {
                    String propertyValue = ra.getContent().toString();
                    properties.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
                }
            }

            return this.createDataSource(properties, nameCtx);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public javax.sql.DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties, Context context) throws Exception {
        PoolConfiguration poolProperties = parsePoolProperties(properties);
        if (poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI() != null && poolProperties.getDataSource() == null) {
            this.performJNDILookup(context, poolProperties);
        }

        String dialect = properties.getProperty(PROP_DIALECT);
        if (dialect == null) {
            log.error("Dialect is unspecified");
            return null;
        }

        CustomDataSource dataSource = new CustomDataSource(dialect, poolProperties);
        dataSource.createPool();
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

CustomDataSource implementation (extends org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource):

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomDataSource extends DataSource {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String dialect;

    public CustomDataSource(String dialect, PoolConfiguration poolProperties) {
        super(poolProperties);
        this.dialect = dialect;
    }
}
```

This somewhat works - when I restart Tomcat, the first webapp (e.g. the one using jdbc/service1DB datasource) starts successfully and uses the configured dialect and operates normally, but all the other ones fail with an error during datasource lookup. Also, when I deploy the webapps without Tomcat restart, the same error occurs (even with the first webapp which previously successfully started after Tomcat restart):

```
"org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException":"Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/service2DB'; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: The local resource link [service2DB] that refers to global resource [jdbc/dbPool] was expected to return an instance of [my.webapp.CustomDataSource] but returned an instance of [my.webapp.CustomDataSource]"
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Where is your `CustomDataSource` located? This is a typical problem of how Tomcat deals with class loaders, try putting your Class on a jar and the jar in tomcat/lib

Comment: It is located in the same package as the class where my DataSource lookup is configured (and CustomDataSourceFactory as well). Therefore it is included in the war of each webapp. I am going to try this just to see if it works, but I would prefer to avoid this method if possible.

Answer (score 3):

## singleton="false"

Aahh, I figured it out.

I did notice that there was only ever one "instance" of CustomDataSource created - after restart there was a tiny indication in the logs stating the datasource was created and then the first webapp started, but no datasources were created again for any of the webapps until another restart.

I re-read the "Adding custom resource factories" chapter in the Tomcat's JNDI resources HOW-TO and noticed the comment about setting the singleton attribute to false (I had read it before but didn't think it was important for my case).

I added it to my datasource. Note the last attribute at bottom.

```
<Resource name = "jdbc/dbPool"
          auth = "Container"
          type = "my.webapp.CustomDataSource"
          maxActive = "100"
          minIdle = "10"
          maxIdle = "30"
          maxWait = "1000"
          username = "username"
          password = "password"
          driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          factory = "my.webapp.CustomDataSourceFactory"
          dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
          url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
          singleton = "false"
/>
```

And it works! All my webapps start and use the dialect I configured!